# Laravel 5.4 version Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::quoutes(). What is the error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I get a

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::quoutes()

error message inside of my Controller, this is how my Controller looks like:

My QuoteController.php:

```
class QuoteController extends Controller

{

    public function postQuote(Request $request)
    {
        $authorText = ucfirst($request['author']);
        $quoteText = $request['quote'];

        $author = Author::where('name', $authorText)->first();
        if (!$author) {
            $author = new Author();
            $author->name = $authorText;
            $author->save();
        } 

        $quote = new Quote();
        $quote->quote = $quoteText;
        $author->quoutes()->save($quote);

        return redirect()->route('index')->with([
            'success' => 'Quote saved!'
        ]);
  }
```

Comment: My guess would be you misspelled `quotes()`, but I'm not sure since you did not post the Author model code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Author code:
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
    public function quotes() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Quote');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the name of quotes wrong:

```
$author->quoutes()->save($quote);
```

Replace it with:

```
$author->quotes()->save($quote);
```